# Python | Using datetime to determine whether the US stock market is open, logic not working correctly

Tags: python, logical-operators

I have this block of code that is supposed to be mentioning whether the stock market is open or not. Holidays aren't included yet.

```
current_time = datetime.now()
local_date = datetime.strftime(current_time, '%b %d, %Y')
print("Today's date is: " + str(local_date))

#Prints out the time on the east coast. Helps give context on market hours.    
eastern_time = datetime.strftime(current_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), '%I:%M %p')

print("Time on the East Coast is currently: " + eastern_time)
day_of_week = datetime.strftime(current_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), '%A')
print(day_of_week)
dt_east = int(datetime.strftime(current_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')), '%H%M'))
print(dt_east)
if 930 <= dt_east <= 1600 and (day_of_week != "Saturday" or day_of_week != "Sunday"):
    print("The market is open!")
else:
    print("The market is closed.")
```

Output:

```
Today's date is: Nov 07, 2021
Time on the East Coast is currently: 12:01 PM
Sunday
1213
The market is open!
```

Printing out `day_of_week` even shows that it's Sunday but returns that the market is open. I ran a quick True/False test and it returns True that it is in fact Sunday.
Not sure what else to try.

Comment: To make it clearer, you can simplify the 2nd part of your logical expression thanks to the `in` keyword.
`if 930 <= dt_east <= 1600 and day_of_week not in ("Saturday", "Sunday"):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# consider the below portion of your if 
(day_of_week != "Saturday" or day_of_week != "Sunday")
```

It returns `True` if either `day_of_week != "Saturday"` or `day_of_week != "Sunday"` is `True`.

Which means, if the day is `Sunday`, `day_of_week != "Saturday"` still return `True` and so the total output is still `True`

You need to replace the `or` with `and`

```
# if 930 <= dt_east <= 1600 and (day_of_week != "Saturday" or day_of_week != "Sunday")
if (930 <= dt_east <= 1600) and (day_of_week != "Saturday") and (day_of_week != "Sunday")
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple function that takes a datetime and returns a boolean

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

def is_market_opened(dt: datetime) -> bool:
    dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
    return 0 <= dt.weekday() <= 4 and 9*60+30 <= dt.hour*60+dt.minute <= 16*60
```

Comment: By using a function you'll be able to add unit testing.
That will be valuable to test for different datetimes, especially when it will get more complex i.e. consider holidays.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

today_str = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days = 3)
end_date = date.today() + timedelta(days = 5)
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
nyse_schedule = nyse.schedule(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
display(nyse_schedule)
if today_str in nyse_schedule.index:
    print(f"Today {today_str} stock market is open.")
    market_status = 1
else:
    print(f"Today {today_str} stock market is NOT open.")
    market_status = 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).